# Localhost port changed but not reflected in WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, port

I've new to WordPress. I've changed my local host PORT from 8080 to 80, its working fine. But in WordPress all the URL's still redirecting to 8080 Port.

**Old URL:**

http://www.virtualhost.com:8080/wp-admin/

**New URL:**

http://www.virtualhost.com/wp-admin/

Is there any WordPress cache or something stored in config?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open phpmyadmin
2. select your databse
3. find wp_options table
4. open your table in browse mode.
5. you can see first two url in value.
6. change it